# Remove rows during a join based on values in other rows using Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause, exists

I am joining multiple tables together and getting a result similar to

```
USER_ID   YEAR    FIELD1   FIELD2  ...
1         2020    --      X
1         2020    --      Y
1         2020    --      Z
1         2020    Value   X
1         2020    Value   Y
1         2020    Value   Z
1         2021    --      X
1         2021    --      Y
1         2021    --      Z
2         2020    --      X
2         2020    --      Y
2         2020    --      Z
2         2020    Value   X
2         2020    Value   Y
2         2020    Value   Z
3         2020    --      X
3         2020    --      Y
3         2020    --      Z
```

I want to remove the rows where FIELD1 is '--' if there are values for the same USER_ID and YEAR where FIELD1 is not '--'. So I should end up with something like this:

```
USER_ID   YEAR    FIELD1   FIELD2  ...
1         2020    Value   X
1         2020    Value   Y
1         2020    Value   Z
1         2021    --      X
1         2021    --      Y
1         2021    --      Z
2         2020    Value   X
2         2020    Value   Y
2         2020    Value   Z
3         2020    --      X
3         2020    --      Y
3         2020    --      Z
```

I do not want to delete the rows from the table where USER_ID, YEAR, and FIELD1 come from. I just want to add the proper where clause to the end of a long join query. I currently have something like this at the end of my join query which works without the where clause:

```
select...
from TABLE1 as t
join...
where t.FIELD1 = '--' and exists(
   select *
   from TABLE1 as t2
      where t.USER_ID= t2.USER_ID and
      t.YEAR = t2.YEAR and
      t2.FIELD1 != '--')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  OR` as it is mutily exclusive to the other condition

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE (FIELD1 = '--' 
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2 WHERE t1.USER_ID =  t2.USER_ID AND  t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR
AND t2.FIELD1 <> '--'))
OR  FIELD1 <> '--' 
ORDER BY USER_ID, YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DENSE_RANK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dense_rank.html) and [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
QUALIFY dense_rank() over (partition by user_id, year, field2 order by FIELD1 = '--') = 1
```

Which is rather concise, and doesn't require any joins or sub-queries.

| USER_ID | YEAR | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,020 | Value | X |
| 1 | 2,020 | Value | Y |
| 1 | 2,020 | Value | Z |
| 1 | 2,021 | -- | X |
| 1 | 2,021 | -- | Y |
| 1 | 2,021 | -- | Z |
| 2 | 2,020 | Value | X |
| 2 | 2,020 | Value | Y |
| 2 | 2,020 | Value | Z |
| 3 | 2,020 | -- | X |
| 3 | 2,020 | -- | Y |
| 3 | 2,020 | -- | Z |

This works because for each `user_id, year, field2` we are ranking the data on it being equal to the lesser wanted `'--'`, given `true` sorts later than `false` the things with 1st equal ranking are "all the non-double hyphen strings" or the hypen-string for that grouping.